# Perform action on return key down

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I perform an action on the **down** press of the return key, not the up press? `textFieldShouldReturn:` only allows the up press.

Alternately, how can I have a `UIActivityIndicatorView` animate at the beginning of an `IBAction` on button up press? Even if it is called first, it doesn't animated until the end, and at that time, it is told to stop animating.

EDIT:

For the second question, here's what happens:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [indicator startAnimating];
    //do stuff...
    usleep(3000000) //to illustrate the problem, wait 3 seconds
}
```

The indicator should start animating first, but it starts animating after the `usleep()`. How do I make it animate before anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the latter question use UIControlEventTouchUpInside.
For example...

```
....
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTchUp)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (void)didTchUp {
    [yourUIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
}
```

usleep() doesn't work because the display is only updated once the main thread returns, at least I think this is why. But a good solution is NSTimer...

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
target:self
selector:@selector(targMtod:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:NO];
```

Comment: I edited my question for clarification on the second question. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

About `UIActivityIndicatorView` you should alloc and then init it. Then UIButton add a subview activityIndicatorView, when you press a button, the action contains `[activityIndicatorView startAnimating]`